# Filter an ArrayList via Optional in Java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I am getting an exception while trying to filter and iterate over a Optional using Java 8. I have an object Subject which is being added in an array list and a value of null also.

**Problem Statement:** I have an ArrayList, I want to iterate it, filter it and then based on that, only print that record which fulfills the condition.

```
    package com.example.app;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Optional;


    public class OptionalTest {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

           System.out.println("getSubject: " + getSubjects());
           // print the Subject with the name "Math"
            System.out.println("getSubject " + getSubjects().filter((Subject s) -> s.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Math")));

        }


        private static Optional getSubjects() {

            Subject subject1 = new Subject(1, "Math", (short)2, "");
            Subject subject2 = new Subject(2, "Social Science", (short)4, "Social Science");
            Subject subject3 = new Subject(3, "English", (short)6, "Literature");

            List<Subject> subjects = new ArrayList<>();
            Optional<List<Subject>> optional = Optional.of(subjects);

            subjects.add(subject1);
            subjects.add(subject2);
            subjects.add(null); 
            subjects.add(subject3);

            return optional;
        }

    }

    class Subject {
        int id;
        String name;
        short type;
        String description;

        public Subject(int id, String name, short type, String description) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.type = type;
            this.description = description;
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public short getType() {
            return type;
        }

        public void setType(short type) {
            this.type = type;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        public void setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "\nSubject{" + "id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", type=" + type + ", description=" + description + '}'+"\n";
        }


    }
```

Comment: 1. Please provide [mcve]. 2. I cannot see any attempt of you trying to solve the problem. 3. You cannot iterate over `Optional` - it's a single value or null. 4. Why do you want to have `Optional` of `List`?

Comment: agreed, but optional can have any object, I am passing it an arrayList of Subject. So to avoid null exception, I am trying to use optional to design the API. Because when we fetch data from the db, it's normally not a single record and could get multiple records or zero

Comment: may be you want a `List<Optional<Subject>>` instead? that would make a lot more sense

Comment: First topic to study: [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/2711488)

Comment: @Eugene not really. The OP is trading a `NullPointerException` for a `NoSuchElementException`. The simplest solution is, *if an element doesn’t exist, don’t add it to the list*. Not to add `null`, not to add an `Optional`, just not to add anything…

Comment: @vicky "it's normally not a single record and could get multiple records or zero" - it's still just a list, might be an empty one, but a list. Not optional of list...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Optional.filter` would be used to filter List instances as per your code snippet. This is not what you want:

```
Optional.of(getSubjects()).filter(predicate) //filters lists, not subjects in lists
```

Your intention is probably to use the a list of `Subject` objects, then filter. It's the `filter` method of the `Stream` interface that returns an `Optional` instance:

I'd change this method:

```
private static List<Subject> getSubjects(){

    Subject subject1 = new Subject(1, "Math", (short)2, "");
    Subject subject2 = new Subject(2, "Social Science", (short)4, "Social Science");
    Subject subject3 = new Subject(3, "English", (short)6, "Literature");

    List<Subject> subjects = new ArrayList<>();

    subjects.add(subject1);
    subjects.add(subject2);
    subjects.add(null); 
    subjects.add(subject3);

    return subjects;
}
```

And then use it as follows:

```
Optional<Subject> filtered = getSubjects()
  .stream().filter(s -> s.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Math"))
  //Find first is just one of the many Stream methods
  //returning an optional
  //It's correct to use it in this case because you know
  //only one value is expected to match the filter predicate.
  .findFirst();
```

In fact, if you expect **more than one** subject to match your filter, you should collect, instead, instead of picking one. In this case, you don't need an optional:

```
List<Subject> mathSubjects = getSubjects()
  .stream().filter((s -> s.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Math")))
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: *The class java.util.Optional doesn't have a method called filter* - you mean besides the one that it does?

Comment: thanks, will the s.getName() handle the null object?

Comment: @vicky If you need to handle nulls, then you can filter out null names: `.filter(s -> s.getName() != null).filter((s -> s.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Math")))`

Comment: @ErnestKiwele *or* `.filter(s -> "Math".equalsIgnoreCase(s.getName()))`

Comment: @Eugene Yep, as long as the string doesn't need to be dynamic.

Comment: The whole point here was using optional and not writing any null checks. So, it can't be used in this situation or in a manner I originally wanted to?

Comment: In fact, you can, technically speaking. An optional of lists can be filtered (you could write a predicate that filters lists, but the result would be the unmodified original list, which you'd have to convert to filtered subject elements anyway). In other words, you don't need an optional of lists when what you're looking for is an optional of Subjects.

Comment: so, return type Optional to avoid nulls is not that practical or make sense, so it's one of the limitations of optional. Now I am wondering how to design a webserivce around Optional. Or just ignore it.

Comment: That's the use it's designed for, in fact. But `Optional<List<Subject>>` has a completely different meaning from `Optional<Subject>`. You want to say **I may or may not return you a subject**, not **I'll return you a list that may or may not contain a subject**. `Optional<Subject>` is more appropriate in your case because your callers are looking for subjects, not lists of subjects, as far as I understand

Comment: @ErnestKiwele thus my initial comment, may be the OP actually needs `List<Optional<Subject>>` to begin with

Comment: Agreed, for a single record, there is no confusion, I can always use optional as a return type, but what if, I am returning a list, which could be null or there could be null values in the list?

Comment: @vicky if you're returning a list of subjects, then it's perfectly correct (and advised as best practice) to return an empty list when there's no element that matches filters. [the only thing to avoid is return null when the return type is a collection]. Returning `Optional<List<Subject>>` is NOT preferred to `List<Subject>`, in my opinion, because in the end it's about subjects.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it very simply using lambda expression, I am providing you a sample so that you can modify according to your need.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

public class Java8Optional {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<>();

    employeeList.add(new Employee(1, "syed"));
    employeeList.add(new Employee(2, "az"));
    employeeList.add(null);
    employeeList.add(new Employee(4, "Rof"));

    employeeList.forEach(n -> Optional.ofNullable(n).ifPresent(e -> System.out.println("Employee ID="+e.employeeId+"\tEmployee Name="+e.employeeName)));

}

static class Employee {

    Integer employeeId;
    String employeeName;

    public Integer getEmployeeId() {
        return employeeId;
    }

    public void setEmployeeId(Integer employeeId) {
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
    }

    public String getEmployeeName() {
        return employeeName;
    }

    public void setEmployeeName(String employeeName) {
        this.employeeName = employeeName;
    }

    public Employee(Integer employeeId, String employeeName) {
        super();
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
        this.employeeName = employeeName;
    }
  }
}
```